# json from java missing square brackets

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, http-post

I am creating JSON using ObjectMapper from jackson. Looking in the debugger I was able to see that '[' was missing before, and ']' was missing after the generated json string (the string json variable in the below function). So as a workaround I put in

```
String str = "["+json+"]";
```

and this resolved the issue. Im worried this might cause bugs in the future and wonder if there is a better approach?

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
  String jsonFixed = "["+json+"]";
```

JSON STRING (WITHOUT '[' BEFORE AND ']' AFTER)

```
{"organisationid":"2345612ß","projectid":"12345678",
"place":{"placeId":"2345","last_place":"123-3"},
"user":{"isY":"false","isHere":"false","isBuyer":"false"},
"x":{"identifier":"SHDG-28CHD"},
"event_type":"x_depart"}
```

Comment: The JSON is not missing the square brackets. Square brackets in JSON indicate an array. You are serializing an individual object, not an array, so there are no square brackets. By adding square brackets, you have transformed the JSON from a representation of an object to a representation of an array of an object, of length 1. See the JSON specification for further reading: http://json.org/

Comment: @Afforess that should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposted from my earlier comment:

The JSON is not missing the square brackets. Square brackets in JSON indicate an array. You are serializing an individual object, not an array, so there are no square brackets. By adding square brackets, you have transformed the JSON from a representation of an object to a representation of an array of an object, of length 1.

See the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) for further reading.